# D365 New Button creates price line with empty line

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-365-operations

After adding logic about creating price for object in grid it's always created "one line more" which is empty. 
So, if there is need to be created two lines, it will be created 3 lines and that one addition will be empty.

Is there something what I missing in code?

```
   [Control("CommandButton")]
    class AreaActionPaneNew
    {
        void clicked()
        {
            PMCParameters   contractParameters = PMCParameters::find();
            PMETmpRentalObjectArea  groupedAreaList; // Group by area_type and cost_type
            PMERentalObjectPrice    priceList;
            date workingDate = currWorkingDate.dateValue();
            ;
            super();

            // Get grouped area values. Values are summed up by area_type and ancost_type
            groupedAreaList = PMERentalObjectAreaCl::getRentalAreaPrCostType(pmeRentalobject.RentalObjectId, userSetting.validFrom(), userSetting.validTo() , workingDate);

            ttsbegin;
            while select groupedAreaList
            {
                select forupdate firstonly priceList
                    where priceList.RentalObjectId == pmeRentalObject.RentalObjectId &&
                          priceList.RentalCostType == groupedAreaList.RentalCostTypeId &&
                          priceList.AreaType == groupedAreaList.Areatype && priceList.ValidFrom == pmeRentalObject.ValidFrom;

                if (!priceList)
                    priceList.initValue();

                priceList.RentalObjectId = pmeRentalObject.RentalObjectId;
                priceList.RentalCostType = groupedAreaList.RentalCostTypeId;
                priceList.ValidFrom      = pmeRentalobject.ValidFrom;

                priceList.AreaType       = groupedAreaList.Areatype;


   priceList.Amount         = groupedAreaList.Price;
            priceList.Area           = groupedAreaList.AreaValue;
            priceList.Quantity       = groupedAreaList.RentalQty;

            if (!priceList)
                priceList.Period  = contractParameters.ReportPeriod;

            if (priceList)
                priceList.update();
            else
                priceList.insert();
        }
        ttscommit;

        pmeRentalObjectPrice_ds.research();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code looks like it only updates/inserts without creating a blank line.

From your attribute, you are using a `Command Button` ([see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamicsax-2012/developer/action-pane-button-overview)), which may have an associated command, such as `New`, which effectively pushes `Ctrl+N`, and would explain why you have a blank line.

The simplest way to check is just create a regular `Button` and override the clicked method, then copy/paste your code and push both buttons and see if they have different behavior.

Check the `Command` property on the button and see if there's something there. Try commenting out the `super();` call.

You should perhaps consider just a `Button` or a `Menu Item Button` with an associated object.

Comment: Created new button. Thanks